# How do bullfrogs eat?

Tags: behaviour, diet, amphibians

I have a very small pond in my backyard and a bullfrog lives in it. I see him all the time, but I never see him eat anything. He either sits in the water with his head just above the water or he sits on a rock next to the pond.

He must be eating something, because he is getting bigger, but I never see him eating. Does he just eat late at night or early in the morning or something? How come I never see him eating?

Comment: Just because you did not happen to see it eating doesn't mean it is not eating. This is not even a controlled experiment. How much time have you spent in observing it?? You have been a member of this site long enough to know that questions like these are absurd. Moreover, it lacks adequate background (for instance, the species of frog).

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered by further research that bullfrogs hunt primarily at night.

So, at night he is probably venturing into the lawn around the pond where there are various insects and smaller frogs, such as wood frogs, available to eat.